# Getting last char sent to std::cout

Tags: c++, iostream, cout

I need at the end of main() execution to check if last char sent to stdout (through `std::cout`) was `'\n'` (or platform specific end-of-line).  How to test for this?  It is safe to assume that C style io (like printf) was not used.

Program is REPL for C++. It evaluates C++ expressions (or statements) and prints results on stdout. It is desirable that output would be always terminated with single new-line.

Comment: Why? What are you trying to do?

Comment: It's usually better to ask about the problem not the step but `std::cin.get()` ought to work.

Comment: Does "last" mean "final" or "most recent"?

Comment: @AJG85, `cin` controls standard _input_, not standard _output_

Comment: @Falmarri - program is repl for c++.  It evaluates c++ expressions (or statements) and prints results on stdout.  It is desirable that output would be always terminated with new-line.

Comment: @Lol4t0: And `cos` is the "C output stream"!

Comment: @KerrekSB, funny but you missed. I am currently studding сhristian philosophy.

Comment: @KerrekSB - most recent.  Not sure I understand though. Program is single threaded.

Comment: Oops my bad misinterpreted the intent. In that case perhaps just redirect stdout to a stringstream and manipulate buffer there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is similar answer to this given by @Kevin. However I believe it is better for your needs. Instead of using some your stream in place of cout -  you can replace streambuf from std::cout with your own:

```
int main() {
   std::streambuf* cbuf = std::cout.rdbuf(); // back up cout's streambuf
   std::cout.flush();
   keep_last_char_outbuf keep_last_buf(cbuf);
   std::cout.rdbuf(&keep_last_buf);          // assign your streambuf to cout

   std::cout << "ala ma kota\n";

   char last_char = keep_last_buf.get_last_char();
   if (last_char == '\r' || last_char == '\n')
      std::cout << "\nLast char was newline: " << int(last_char) << "\n";
   else
      std::cout << "\nLast char: '" << last_char << "'\n";

   std::cout << "ala ma kota";
   last_char = keep_last_buf.get_last_char();
   if (last_char == '\r' || last_char == '\n')
      std::cout << "\nLast char was newline: " << int(last_char) << "\n";
   else
      std::cout << "\nLast char: '" << last_char << "'\n";

   std::cout.rdbuf(cbuf); // restore cout's original streambuf
}
```

And expected output:

```
ala ma kota

Last char was newline: 10
ala ma kota
Last char: 'a'
```

A task to write such `class keep_last_char_outbuf` is not very easy, Look for decorator pattern and [streambuf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/streambuf/) interface.

If you don't have time for playing with this - look at my proposal [ideone link](http://ideone.com/HbQ2r)

```
class keep_last_char_outbuf : public std::streambuf {
public:
    keep_last_char_outbuf(std::streambuf* buf) : buf(buf), last_char(traits_type::eof()) {
        // no buffering, overflow on every char
        setp(0, 0);
    }
    char get_last_char() const { return last_char; }

    virtual int_type overflow(int_type c) {
        buf->sputc(c);
        last_char = c;
        return c;
    }
private:
    std::streambuf* buf;
    char last_char;
};
```

Comment: This was exactly what I needed! Thank you. This will be incorporated into http://volnitsky.com/project/scc project

Comment: @Leonid - It is nice to know that. Please remember two things, I do not care in my solutions: 1) multithreading 2) setting external buffer via `cout.rdbuf()->pubsetbuf(...)` after setting   `keep_last_char_outbuf`.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of printing to `cout`, you could define your own stream-like object that accepts the standard `ostream` operators/functions, but keeps track of the most recently printed character as it passes the operations on to the real `cout`.