# C++ Wrap cin and cout in class - Overload << and >> operators

Tags: c++, stream, operator-overloading, cout, cin

I am trying to make a Console class. I would like to wrap `cin` and `cout` in the class and overload the `<<` and `>>` operators. So I could use the class as such:

```
// Output
Console << "Call cout from Console" << endl;

// Input
string str;
Console >> str; // Call cin
```

My best guess was:

```
class Console {
//...
public:
    ostream& operator<< (ostream& os)
    {
        cout << os;
        return &cout;
    }
    //...
};
```

But I know that's wrong, how could I overload the operators to use the Console class as both `cin` and `cout`?

Comment: You're probably going to want a singleton object for that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got a working code that can handle the stream manipulators. You can see my code in action [in this Ideone page](http://ideone.com/Y60xz)

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>

typedef std::ostream& (*manip) (std::ostream&);

class console {

};

template <class T> console& operator<< (console& con, const T& x) { std::cout << x; return con; }
template <class T> console& operator>>(console& con,  T& x) { std::cin >>x; return con; }
console& operator<< (console& con, manip manipulator){ std::cout<<manipulator; return con;}

int main() {
    console c;
    int a,b;
    c>>a>>b;
    c << "hello world"<<std::endl<<std::hex<<(a+b)<<std::endl;
}
```

Thanks @MooingDuck for the discussion that led me to a working answer and @111111 for the start point.

Comment: That seems like exactly what I'm looking for I'm going to try it out now. And by the way I intended on making it a singleton someone mentioned that in a comment, I can declare the operator overloads static right?

Comment: Wait, shouldnt the operators be in the class body or be declared friends with it?

Comment: @BrandonMiller I don't need to declare `friend `because I am not accessing private members of `console`. I can either declare in the class `console`, so I don't need to pass a `console` reference in the parameter list or I can do the way I did above.

Comment: @BrandonMiller operators must operate over instances, so they cannot be declared static.

Comment: Yes I should have tested it first. This works great thank you!

Comment: How would I make this a singleton?

Comment: Although this WORKS, it only allows trivial wrapping of stdin/out with very little functionality. However it is more direct; it will work with binary sources better than my solution.

Comment: @BrandonMiller to make it a singleton, declare the struct as console_, then in the global namespace, do console_ console; Of course there's always the singleton problem, wherein if you use that singleton before it is constructed (and it has additional functionality), you're screwed. If you have a constructor and such, you may wish to use the idiom where you return a reference to a static pointer that allocates the space for console_ from function console(). console_& console() { static *console_ local = new console_; return *local; }

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why would want to do such a thing but it isn't the stream you need to capture but the other type. But if this is just to make std::cout and std::cin more convenient I wouldn't bother.

```
class console {

};

template<typename T>
console& operator<<(console con, const T& val) {
     std::cout << val;
     return con;
}

console c;
c << "hello world\n";
```

Comment: Can you test `c << "hello world" << std::endl`. I am afraid there are more `operator <<` to define than `template <class T> ostream& operator(..., const T&)`.

Comment: neat trick.  unfortunately: [error: no match for ‘operator<<’](http://ideone.com/igC07)

Comment: Indeed, see my answer for a refinement. The reason that yours fails is "console con" should be "console& con", since console doesn't provide a copy constructor and thus cannot be passed by value (copied). However in my answer I also solved the problem of using more than one argument, and buffering the output, and not having to get into arcane black magic of keeping an std::ostream yourself.

Comment: @std''OrgnlDave if you do not provider a copy constructor , the compiler provides one to you, doing a copy of field by field

Comment: My reason for wanting it is because I have input and output routines and I'm going to group the methods and other miscellaneous functions, i'm also making a CommandMap class so i can execute certion methods when the user types a certian keyword

Comment: Just trying to shorten code writing, I just needed that as the basis

Comment: @AndréOriani that only works with trivial copy-constructors. Anyhow, you're making a new variable on the stack and returning a reference to that new variable; since you return, the reference to that area is now invalid.

Comment: @std''OrgnlDave yes , the compiler will generate a trivial copy-constructor. And I  also agree with you that the parameter must be a reference to console. The gcc warns about the problem you mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

This is not direct answer to your question, but maybe I point you out some alternative.

See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12060581/getting-last-char-sent-to-stdcout/12061076#12061076) to some other question. To define yourself all of these `<<`and `>>` operators is not very easy. However you can overwrite streambuf for Console. Use combined streambufs of cin and cout,

Derive your console from `std::iostream` and your streambuf from `std::streambuf`

```
class console_streambuf : public std::streambuf {
public:
    console_streambuf() {
        // no buffering, overflow on every char
        setp(0, 0);
    }
    virtual int_type overflow(int_type c) {
        std::cout << c;
        return c;
    }
    ...
};

class console : public std::iostream {
public:
    console() { rdbuf(&buf); }
private:
    console_streambuf buf; 
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to many of the answers above, doing what you want is pretty simple, using the magic of templates.

I'd recommend using a stringstream, because using an ostream (cout is an ostream) can require arcane black magic (no joke).

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

struct console {
  std::stringstream  data_;

  console() : data_() {  };

  // We make ourselves a template sink so we can "take" operator<<'s.
  //  The awesome advantage to using a template like this is that the
  //  compiler will allow us to "take" any data that can be converted
  //  to a stringstream, which will handle converting int's etc.
  //  for us!
  template<typename T>
  console& operator<<(const T& what) {
    data_ << what;
    return *this;  // We must return a reference if we want to
                   //  string together more than one thing, i.e.
                   //  b << " " << 4;
  }

  void flush() {
    std::cout << data_.str();
    data_.clear();
    std::cout.flush();
  }
};

int main()
{
  int a = 4;
  console b;
  console c;
  b.data_ << 2;
  c.data_ << 4;
  //b << std::cout;  // WHAT? it's possible but stupid, prints garbage

  // Because we made the template return a reference, this will
  //  allow us to chain things just like we do with cout.
  b << " HELLO WORLD! " << "yo!" << 4;

  b << a << " " << 4.2f;

  // Compiler chokes on this. It will try to convert "console"
  //  to a stringstream which it can't.
  //b << c;

  b.flush(); // Send out the output

  // Wait for key press
  char foo[500];
  gets(foo);
}
```

Output:

```
2 HELLO WORLD! yo!44 4.2
```

Just like cout, except of course with more control.
You can get into using basic_ostream's and basic_istreams if you want binary I/O, but I'd recommend against it unless you really really need it.

Comment: @MooingDuck why would you want to buffer the console? "more control." can you tell cout *not* to flush until you want it to? you probably can and I don't know how...

Answer (score -1):

Overloaded operator functions must be declared with the specific types you're going to call them with on the left and right.  So you will need an `operator<< (int)`, `operator<< (double)`, `operator<< (const std::string &)`, etc.

If you're really just going to pass them on to cin and cout, you can save typing by using a template member function, like:

```
template <class T> Console& operator<< (const T& x) { cout << x; return *this; }
```

[thanks to André for pointing out it should return Console& so you can string together calls like `Console << a << b;` ]

Comment: There two problems: first you are not returnin a ostream object. Second to make `console` work like `cout` or `cin` you should return a `console&`

Comment: @AndréOriani: I disagree, he _is_ returning an ostream object, and so `ostream&` _was_ the right return type.

Comment: @MooingDuck perhaps you got in the middle of our talking and lost the context. Previous code did not return anything at all. He "fixed", but code is still wrong. Return statement should be `return *this;` so a `console` reference is returned. Do we agree now?  We should return the wrapper , not the wrapped object.

Comment: @MooingDuck okay now I see my mistake. I thought it was a member method. So what I said must be ignored, since it is no sense.

Comment: It was supposed o be a member method. I fixed it to return *this, thanks.